# pg_dump with -w flag does not read from .pgpass file

Tags: backup, postgresql

I am trying to backup my PostgreSQL database called *crewdb* on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from a script with the following command in it:

`pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w -C -F p -b -v -f ~/Dropbox\/postgres_backup/crewdb.backup.sql crewdb`

I know the script that the above command runs in, itself works. When I run the above command with -W instead of -w I am prompted for a password and the backup goes ahead nicely. I am trying to automate this command within the script and want the backup to go ahead without prompting for a password thus with the -w flag. To this end I created the following file

`/home/chh1/.pgpass`

When `ls -la ~/.pgpass`

`-rw------- 1 chh1 chh1 74 Oct 15 10:00 .pgpass`

Inside the file .pgpass I placed the following text:

`# Server:Port:Database:Username:Password`

`*:*:crewdb:postgres:9Gh#$mq`

However when I run the command I get the following error output and the backup fails:

`pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w -C -F p -b -v -f ~/Dropbox\/postgres_backup/crewdb.backup.sql crewdb`

`pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "crewdb" failed: FATAL:` 
 `password authentication failed for user "postgres"`
`password retrieved from file "/home/chh1/.pgpass"`
`FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`
`password retrieved from file "/home/chh1/.pgpass"`

I do much appreciate if anyone here can put me on the right path!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question has been found.

When running

```
hexdump -C ~/.pgpass
```

I got the following output:

```
00000000  23 20 68 6f 73 74 6e 61  6d 65 3a 70 6f 72 74 3a  |# hostname:port:|
00000010  64 61 74 61 62 61 73 65  3a 75 73 65 72 6e 61 6d  |database:usernam|
00000020  65 3a 70 61 73 73 77 6f  72 64 0a 2a 3a 2a 3a 63  |e:password.*:*:c|
00000030  72 65 77 64 62 3a 70 6f  73 74 67 72 65 73 3a 39  |rewdb:postgres:9|
00000040  47 68 23 24 6d 71 20 0a                           |Gh#$mq .|
00000048
```

The fifth line had a 20 listed pointing to a space at the end of the password but before the end of the line, indicating that there is a space at the end of the password that should not be there.
After removing the space the command executed without any password prompting.

The answer to this question was supplied by  Daniel Vérité from ServerVault.